# Encountered trustAsHtmlFilter when crawling

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

When I tried to crawl this page: http://www.cvs.com/shop/household-grocery/electronics/computer-supplies/avery-pin-fed-printers-computer-label-0-93-in-x-3-in-white-5000-pack-prodid-934273?skuId=934273

using

```
scrapy shell url
```

then do a

```
view(response)
```

I see trustAsHtmlFilter shown on the page. The page layout is there, but all the content is not shown. So I guess the site uses this filter to block my crawler.

I did google it and it seems like this filter comes from AngularJS? not sure about that

So My question are:

1. What might be the reason for triggering this filter? I was crawling this page days ago and it was fine back then.
2. Is there a way to get around this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using a `user agent` with the request ? `scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='user agent' 'http://www.example.com'`

Comment: I used it, still get blocked by that filter

Answer (score 0):

If you open the url in a browser without javascript you will get the same "error". The content you are looking for is dynamically generated with javascript. So you need to be able to deal with js to get the content.

The first option is usually try to identify the request generated by javascript. If you can do that, you can send the same request from scrapy. If you can't do it, the next option is usually to use some package with javascript/browser emulation or someting like that. Something like ScrapyJS or Scrapy + Selenium.